# Blender rescaling rendered image lowers quality

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, antialiasing

I recently rendered an image in blender. Now, the issue is, when I down scale the image the quality seems to lower as I can identify individual pixels. I'm not entirely sure if this is aliasing (and if it is, it would be nice if someone could explain *how* this is caused by aliasing) and whether setting anti-aliasing in blender would work. See below:

Before

[image]

After[image]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Avoid using MS Paint for such things. Paint applies scale immediately after operation so if you drag scaling 2 times, the quality will be lost twice. In any image editor like Photoshop or Gimp you can scale image, preview result and then apply it. I'd say Blender isn't related in this case, rather than image editor program used.

Comment: you can also set the render dimensions in blender.